# Is $\mathbb{P}(X^2>a)=\mathbb{P}(X>\sqrt{a})$, $a>0$?

Tags: probability, convergence

Let $X$ be a r.v. and $a>0$

Is $$\mathbb{P}(X^2>a)=\mathbb{P}(X>\sqrt{a})$$ ?

---

As seen in the comments, no. It should be:

$$\mathbb{P}(X^2>a)=\mathbb{P}(|X|>\sqrt{a})$$

---

But why does probability follow this kind of "linearity"?

Comment: Hint: What happens when $X$ can be less than $-\sqrt{a}$?

Comment: $$(-3)^2>4$$ so $(-3)>2$, hmm...

Comment: Aha. Should be $\mathbb{P}(X^2>a)=\mathbb{P}(|X|>\sqrt{a})$. Still a bit rusty on probabilities and forget how to think about them like real numbers.

Comment: That last remark is apt: this question isn't about probabilities at all; it is only about properties of real numbers. The notation may obscure the fact that expressions like "$X^2\gt a$" and "$|X|\gt\sqrt{a}$" are merely shorthand for *sets of numbers* such as $\{X\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,X^2\gt a\}$, etc. The probabilities in this case will be equal merely *because the sets are the same.*  Therefore they must have the same probability, no matter what the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ might be.

Comment: @whuber that comment looks like a suitable answer to me, since to my eyes it both explains the mistaken premise (that it's about properties of probabilities rather than properties of sets over the reals) and then gets at the heart of the underlying issue relating to the sets being the same.

Answer (score 4):

$$P(X^2 > a) = P(X > \sqrt a \cup X < -\sqrt a) = P(X > \sqrt a) + P(X < -\sqrt a)$$

The hypothesis can be weakened to $a \ge 0$

Comment: This answer is incorrect when $a=0$ and $X$ has an atom at $0$. It is also incorrect for all negative $a$ (to address the speculation in the last sentence).

Comment: @whuber Wait why isn't a=0 allowed?

Comment: It is (+1).  Upon seeing "$a \ge 0$" in the original post I had also misread your events as being written with greater than or equal signs, too.  What you have written is provably correct for $a \ge 0$ (and would make no sense for $a \lt 0$), because the events $X \gt \sqrt{a}$ and $X \lt -\sqrt{a}$ are disjoint.

Comment: @whuber Now okay?

Comment: One thing to know about Complex numbers is that the ordering $\gt$ of reals does not--it cannot--extend to them.  That's why an expression like "$X \gt \sqrt{a}$" makes no sense for $a \lt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a non-negative random variable then $X^2$ > $a$ and $X$ > $sqrt(a)$ are equivalent events. Therefore the two probabilities are equal.

Comment: And if x is not nonnegative?

Comment: as you already pointed out, the equivalent event for $X^2$ > $a$ is $X > sqrt(a)$ OR $X < -sqrt(a)$ when $X$ could be either positive or negative. i was giving a condition where the identity in the title of the question does hold